# Develop algorithm without any application in mind

Tags: mathematics, research-undergraduate

I am an undergraduate student. My adviser proposed me to develop an algorithm, which is a combination of two existing. So, the idea of the algorithm is clear and the main task is to prove convergence. The problem is that:
1) I cannot find any application for the new algorithm.
2) It seems to me that developing a proof of convergence is rather hard and I feel uncomfortable about it, because I am on my own with the problem.
Is it a typical situation? Is it better to force myself and try to finish the current work or is it better to try to find a new topic?

Comment: What did your advisor say when you asked him about these issues?

Comment: When I asked the adviser about applications he suggested a "synthetic" one (more of a picking specific parameters for a general framework, than a real-life application).

Comment: Your question is confusing: an algorithm [is an unambiguous specification of how to solve a class of problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm). Your title says you don't have an application, but then you say _the main task is to prove convergence_ and _I cannot find any application for the new algorithm_ - well, isn't the aim of the algorithm proving convergence? And then you say something about a _proof_ - of what? As stated, there are too many gaps in the question so that I cannot follow your line of reasoning.

Comment: Ok, I will elaborate. Lets say that I am developing an algorithm for minimizing a function. In my opinion, a proper application will be minimizing loss function of a ml model. A "synthetic" one will be minimizing a quadratic function.

Comment: As for what is the main task, I don't understand why to try hard to prove the convergence of an useless algorithm.

Comment: Have you checked what possible applications the two previously developed algorithms can be used for? Have you understood how the proofs of convergence were done for the other two? Do you enjoy thinking about algorithms?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have two problems here.

First, you seem to have different research preferences from your advisor (from the comments: "I don't understand why to try hard to prove the convergence of an useless algorithm"). In research, there is a wide spectrum of approaches, from purely theoretical to purely applied. Researchers from one end of the spectrum may have a hard time understanding why the research at the other end of the spectrum is worthwhile and/or interesting.

From the comments, you've tried to talk to your advisor about applications. It's possible that such applications exist, but your advisor hasn't thought of them: if they're not application-oriented, this may not be a high priority for them or they may just not be very creative about thinking of possible applications.

Depending on how unhappy you are with this different point of view, you can either (1) suck it up and work on the problem your advisor gave you for a while (keeping an eye out for possible applications) or (2) find another advisor. Asking your advisor for a different problem is a possibility, but given that you've already asked about applications and gotten an unsatisfactory answer, this may not work.

Second, you're concerned that the research problem is too hard: "developing a proof of convergence is rather hard and I feel uncomfortable about it, because I am on my own with the problem". (This is *mostly* a separate question: a problem's intrinsic difficulty is unrelated to its topic, although solving it can be more difficult if you're not motivated.) **If** your advisor is effective, then they will have given you a problem that is within your capability - even if it initially seems too difficult. Depending on your relationship with your advisor, you might be able to ask for starting points and/or reassurance. You might even be able to ask for an easier problem; getting a simpler problem in the same area seems more reasonable than getting a problem outside your supervisor's scope (i.e., an applied problem).

It's a personal decision as to whether you buckle down and work on a problem even if you're not sure you like it and can do it, but my advice - especially if you're just starting - would be to make a sincere effort before changing course.  Your advisor is much more likely to give you help, or let you change problems, if you demonstrate that you've really tried to solve the one they gave you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Will it help to try to ask some specialist in the field (I will need to find such in the internet) about whether it is a feasible task for an undergrad? Also, while I admit that this is not a particular good metric, but I undergrad papers I have seen where up to 10 pages, and the source papers I was given are 20 pages +, so how can I produce anything smaller, based on these papers.

Comment: briefly (may add more later); I would *not* recommend asking people on the internet. Rather, I would suggest **discreet**, low-key inquiries among people close to your level (undergrads, grad students, postdocs) who have more experience with your advisor whether they've had good experiences/been given appropriate problems and guidance. You need to know about your advisor, not about the research problem; if they're a good advisor, then they will be a better judge than you (or than a random stranger on the internet) about appropriate level of difficulty.